# python-clang crashes with segmentation fault

Tags: python, c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, bitcoin

I have the following simple python code which traverse the AST using libclang python bindings, unfortunately it crashes with segmentation fault.
I'm using python2.7 and tried all the following clang versions 3.8, 3.9, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 (and of course used the right python clang bindings for each version)

```
import clang.cindex

def traverse(node):
    print("%-42s %-20s %-10s %-6s %s" % (node.kind, node.spelling, node.type.spelling, node.location.line, node.mangled_name))
    for child in node.get_children():
        traverse(child)

clang.cindex.Config.set_library_file('/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/lib/libclang.so')
index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
tu = index.parse(sys.argv[1], args=['-Werror'])
traverse(tu.cursor)
```

the backtrace :

```
#0  clang::TagType::getDecl (this=0x0) at /build/llvm-toolchain-3.8-_PD09B/llvm-toolchain-3.8-3.8/tools/clang/lib/AST/Type.cpp:2962
#1  0x00007f9ecbe65caf in clang::RecordType::getDecl (this=<optimized out>) at /build/llvm-toolchain-3.8-_PD09B/llvm-toolchain-3.8-3.8/tools/clang/include/clang/AST/Type.h:3554
#2  (anonymous namespace)::CXXNameMangler::mangleUnqualifiedName (this=this@entry=0x7ffe35f45470, ND=ND@entry=0x7f9ec0092cc8, Name=..., 
    AdditionalAbiTags=AdditionalAbiTags@entry=0x7ffe35f453c0, KnownArity=4294967295)
    at /build/llvm-toolchain-3.8-_PD09B/llvm-toolchain-3.8-3.8/tools/clang/lib/AST/ItaniumMangle.cpp:1184
#3  0x00007f9ecbe60250 in (anonymous namespace)::CXXNameMangler::mangleUnqualifiedName (AdditionalAbiTags=0x7ffe35f453c0, ND=<optimized out>, this=0x7ffe35f45470)
    at /build/llvm-toolchain-3.8-_PD09B/llvm-toolchain-3.8-3.8/tools/clang/lib/AST/ItaniumMangle.cpp:481
#4  (anonymous namespace)::CXXNameMangler::mangleLocalName (this=this@entry=0x7ffe35f45470, D=D@entry=0x7f9ec0092cc8, AdditionalAbiTags=AdditionalAbiTags@entry=0x7ffe35f453c0, 
    ExcludeUnqualifiedName=ExcludeUnqualifiedName@entry=false) at /build/llvm-toolchain-3.8-_PD09B/llvm-toolchain-3.8-3.8/tools/clang/lib/AST/ItaniumMangle.cpp:1471
#5  0x00007f9ecbe607b7 in (anonymous namespace)::CXXNameMangler::mangleNameWithAbiTags (this=this@entry=0x7ffe35f45470, ND=ND@entry=0x7f9ec0092cc8, 
    AdditionalAbiTags=AdditionalAbiTags@entry=0x7ffe35f453c0, ExcludeUnqualifiedName=ExcludeUnqualifiedName@entry=false)
    at /build/llvm-toolchain-3.8-_PD09B/llvm-toolchain-3.8-3.8/tools/clang/lib/AST/ItaniumMangle.cpp:801
#6  0x00007f9ecbe61621 in (anonymous namespace)::CXXNameMangler::mangleName (this=0x7ffe35f45470, ND=0x7f9ec0092cc8, ExcludeUnqualifiedName=<optimized out>)
    at /build/llvm-toolchain-3.8-_PD09B/llvm-toolchain-3.8-3.8/tools/clang/lib/AST/ItaniumMangle.cpp:776
#7  0x00007f9ecbe62822 in (anonymous namespace)::ItaniumMangleContextImpl::mangleCXXName (this=<optimized out>, D=0x7f9ec0092cc8, Out=...)
    at /build/llvm-toolchain-3.8-_PD09B/llvm-toolchain-3.8-3.8/tools/clang/lib/AST/ItaniumMangle.cpp:4422
#8  0x00007f9ecbd4df6b in clang_Cursor_getMangling (C=...) at /build/llvm-toolchain-3.8-_PD09B/llvm-toolchain-3.8-3.8/tools/clang/tools/libclang/CIndex.cpp:3996
#9  0x00007f9eccbd2e40 in ffi_call_unix64 () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6
#10 0x00007f9eccbd28ab in ffi_call () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6
```

I'm running the python code on bitcoin source code from github and this backtrace is for the file *src/bitcoin-cli.cpp*

any idea why it crashes ? 
Thanks, Sagi

Comment: it also happens when using latest libclang.so : clang.cindex.Config.set_library_file('/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib/libclang.so')

Comment: Still an issue with libclang 7.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug and is being tracked here: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34484

Answer (score 0):

I found that node.mangled_name causes the crash.